# How to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\binom{n+k}{k}}{(n+k)^k} = \frac{1}{k!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Given that $k\in\mathbb{N}$, my question is how to prove that this sequence converge to $\frac{1}{k!}$:

$$\left\{ \frac{n+k \choose k}{(n+k)^{k}} \right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.$$

I have this attempt:

[image]

Comment: The limit...when what goes to what?

Comment: @Timbuc the simbol at the top of the page is converge to .... :)

Comment: That I know, @user . Is then $\;n\to\infty\;$ ? This must be explicitly given, I believe.

Comment: Well in my problem is just an arbitrary n :)

Comment: So then we don't know what variable tends to what?

Comment: yes that is right :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it is $\;n\to\infty\;$ and $\;k\;$ is a constant, we get:

$$\frac{\binom{n+k}k}{(n+k)^k}=\frac{(n+k)!}{k!\,n!\,(n+k)^k}=\frac1{k!}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n+k)}{(n+k)^k}=$$

$$=\frac1{k!}\frac{n+1}{n+k}\frac{n+2}{n+k}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n+k}{n+k}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1{k!}\cdot1\cdot1\cdot\ldots\cdot1$$

Comment: Thank you @Timbuc but do I can say it like that, dont you have to use $\epsilon$ and that things? :)

Comment: Nobody, after learning the formal definition of limit **and then** some arithmetic of limits, goes back to the epsilon thing...unless explicitly required.

Comment: Well since this problem do not say anything about it, hhahahahaha thak you @Timbuc :)